# QC REST API : Unsupported Media Type

Tags: api, rest, attachment, multipart, hp-quality-center

We use HP Quality Center and we upgrade 11.5x to 12.21 and i use the API to create a ticket. Connexion and ticket creation are ok, but attachement of file is not.

I got `{"Id":"qccore.general-error","Title":"Unsupported Media Type","ExceptionProperties":null,"StackTrace":null}`

Here is my code

```
$filename = $file->name;
$eol = "\r\n";
$mime_boundary = 'boundary';

$content = '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$content .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity.type"';
$content .= $eol . $eol;
$content .= 'defect';
$content .= $eol;

$content = '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$content .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity.id"';
$content .= $eol . $eol;
$content .= $id;
$content .= $eol;

$content = '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$content .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"';
$content .= $eol . $eol;
$content .= utf8_encode($filename);
$content .= $eol;

$content .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$content .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' . utf8_encode($filename) . '"';
$content .= $eol;
$content .= 'Content-Type: ' . $file['type'];
$content .= $eol . $eol;

$dt = explode('-', $file->create_dt);
$path_file = $config['files']['forms_attachments_path'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dt[0] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dt[1] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->filename;
$handle = fopen($path_file, 'r');
$content .= fread($handle,filesize($path_file));
fclose($handle);

$content .= $eol;
$content .= '--' . $mime_boundary . '--';

$header = array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary='.$mime_boundary,
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($content),
    'Accept: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookiess);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, null);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['qc']['url'] . '/api/domains/' . $config['qc']['domain']. '/projects/' . $config['qc']['project'] . '/attachments/');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);
```

If i use the other multipart/form-data i got `{"Id":"qccore.general-error","Title":"Illegal multi-part arguments. Attachment wasn't created.","ExceptionProperties":null,"StackTrace":null}`

So i have a multipart structure mistake or a bad header for content-type, but all we test fails.

We try to put attachment by octet stream method but got the media type error.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

We use a slightly different endpoint. I noticed that, although many "old" endpoints still work in HP ALM 12.x, some of them changed their behaviour a lot, and most of them have replacements which should be used instead.

We use
`/rest/domains/DOMAIN/projects/PROJECT/defects/4711/attachments` 
(instead of `/api/...` and passing entity ID via form fields).

Then, we add an HTTP Header `Slug: myfilename.txt`

Our other HTTP Headers are:

```
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Now, we only POST the file data to that endpoint. That works fine with HP ALM 12.50.

Also see http://stevenckwong.com/wp/2016/05/09/how-to-upload-an-attachment-to-a-test-in-alm-via-the-rest-api/ for a similar example (also Java code, sorry).